# Hadoop program without reading contents of the file

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, mapper, reducers

It maybe a basic question but in the map reduce program, I would like to read the names of all the files present in the inputfolder rather than the contents and i would like to send the names of those files to my mapper class. 
Configuration conf=new Configuration();

```
    Job job=new Job(conf,"Analysis");
    job.setInputFormatClass(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
    //Path pa =new Path("hdfs://localhost:54310/home/aparajith");
    //pa.

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job,new Path("/hduser/"));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("/CrawlerOutput23/"));

    job.setJarByClass(mapper.Mapper1.class);

    job.setMapperClass(mapper.Mapper1.class);
    job.setReducerClass(mapper.Reducer1.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : -1);
```

This is my main class and I cant seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest solution is to put all the names of the file in that directory in a file and give that file as input file to the job

Answer (score 1):

### If you want the names of the files keys and values are coming from in your mapper:

In your mapper you could simply ignore the key and value that are passed in (by default the position in file as a `LongWritable` key and the line content as `Text` value) and do something like the following:

```
@Override
protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String fileName = ((FileSplit) context.getInputSplit()).getPath().getName();
    // insert remaining mapper logic here
}
```

This gets the file name from which the current key and value in the mapper were read.

---

### If you just want the file names in your directory as input to your mapper:

You could iterate over the files in your input directory (`yourInputDirPath`) and write a new file containing their filenames (`inputDirFilenamesPath`) like so:

```
    FSDataOutputStream stream;
    try {
        stream = fs.create(inputDirFilenamesPath);
        RemoteIterator<LocatedFileStatus> it = fs.listFiles(yourInputDirPath, false);
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            stream.write(it.next().getPath().toString().getBytes());
            stream.write('\n');
        }
    } finally {
        stream.close();
    }
```

Then you can simply use `FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, inputDirFilenamesPath);` to add this file to your input to the MR job.

Comment: but in this case , if file gets splitted then same file name would be repested multiple times.
In this case you would need a custom file inputformat and there you have to override issplittable and return false from it